# Python: Iterating through a dictionary gives me "int object not iterable"

Tags: python, dictionary, loops

Here's my function:

```
def printSubnetCountList(countList):
    print type(countList)
    for k, v in countList:
        if value:
            print "Subnet %d: %d" % key, value
```

Here's the output when the function is called with the dictionary passed to it:

```
<type 'dict'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compareScans.py", line 81, in <module>
    printSubnetCountList(subnetCountOld)
  File "compareScans.py", line 70, in printSubnetCountList
    for k, v in countList:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to consider adding type hints to your code for better readability (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

Answer (score 54):

Try this

```
for k in countList:
    v = countList[k]
```

Or this

```
for k, v in countList.items():
```

Read this, please: [Mapping Types — `dict` — Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

Answer (score 20):

The `for k, v` syntax is a short form of the tuple unpacking notation, and could be written as `for (k, v)`. This means that every element of the iterated collection is expected to be a sequence consisting of exactly two elements. But iteration on dictionaries yields only keys, not values.

The solution is it use either `dict.items()` or `dict.iteritems()` (lazy variant), which return sequence of key-value tuples.

Comment: `iteritems()` works in **Python2**, but not in **Python3** where its equivalent is `items()` [SO related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418481/error-dict-object-has-no-attribute-iteritems/30418498)

Answer (score 2):

You can't iterate a dict like this. See example:

```
def printSubnetCountList(countList):
    print type(countList)
    for k in countList:
        if countList[k]:
            print "Subnet %d: %d" % k, countList[k]
```