# Python - TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable for dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I've looked elsewhere and cant find a soloution for my specific example. I have a dictonary of keys with a number value assigned to them. In order to find the key that matches a specific number I wrote a for loop like this:

```
for key, num in dict.values():
         if num == n:
             #do stuff
```

I had already predefined n in my code earleir so thats not the problem. I have tried doing int(num) and int(n) and both at the same time but nothing seems to work. Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Iterating through a dictionary gives me "int object not iterable"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750664/python-iterating-through-a-dictionary-gives-me-int-object-not-iterable)

Answer (score 4):

You want:

```
for key, num in dict.items() :
```

instead. Values gives you iteration over the key values only, `.items()` iterates over tuples of `(key, value)`.

Note: as per comment from iCodez, if you're using python 2.x you should prefer `.iteritems()` since in earlier versions of python `.items()` would create an unnecessary copy of the list.

Comment: Note that in Python 2.x, you should use `dict.iteritems` to avoid creating an unnecessary list.